# Регулировка расстояния между дочерними элементами flex-block'a

Tags: html, css

Как можно регулировать расстояние между flex-элементами при следующих свойствах

```
display: flex; 
flex-flow: column wrap; 
align-items: center;
justify-align: center;
```

?
Заранее спасибо за ответ...

Comment: Margin ? Padding?
-- justify-content NOT -align
column wrap - мне кажется вообще бесполезная штука. Если все элементы внутри бокса идут в столбик, к чему там вообще wrap?
какой результат должен получится?

Comment: @NeedHate, ну, нужно было, чтобы все отступы были равны при любом масштабе страницы...

Answer (score 2):

Если ваш вопрос понят правильно, то чтоб было расстояние между блоками (вокруг них), находящимися столбиком, надо `"justify-content: center"` изменить на `"justify-content: space-around"`.

Описание: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp

Пример: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_justify-content&preval=initial

---

СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ за выложенные свойства. Помогло мне для установки и регулирования положения блоков при любом масштабе страницы. Были добавлены в container, `"column wrap"` изменён на `"inline wrap"`. И `"justify-align: center"` не ведомый мне тег, был изменён на `"justify-content: center"`.

Comment: Привет, добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow. Вы опубликовали ответ — в нём должен быть именно ответ на вопрос. Поскольку в комментарии ниже было что-то очень похожее на ответ, я перенёс это в сам ответ.